# create layout through code

Tags: android

I created layout through code so that i can add multiple views on that layout using code below.

```
public class AndroidPrepChart extends Activity {

    GraphicalView gView;
    GraphicalView gView2;
    GraphicalView gView3;

    BarChart barChart = new BarChart();
    BarChart2 barChart2 = new BarChart2();
    BarChart3 barChart3 = new BarChart3();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gView = barChart.execute2(this);
        gView2 = barChart2.execute2(this);
        gView3 = barChart3.execute2(this);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

        layout.addView(gView, 150, 200);
        layout.addView(gView2, 150, 200);
        layout.addView(gView3, 150, 150);

        setContentView(layout);

     }
}
```

Here output screen contains three charts but i want to position third chart in the second line. Please help me to solve this problem. I am beginner in Android.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by nesting multiple `LinearLayout`s and changing the orientation property

in XML this would look something like this (showing only the relevant elements and attributes):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Your first 2 graphs go in this LinearLayour -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- The third graph goes in here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can programmatically manipulate the orientation of the `LinearLayout` by using the [setOrientation method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation%28int%29). E.g:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you completely sure that you can't do it with an XML? Coding gui from the code is quite more difficult.

In relation to your question:
I guess you want the third `GraphicalView` to be to the right of the second one.

Two ways to do it:
Using a `RelativeLayout` or using a second `LinearLayout`.

Example:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.addView(gView, 150, 200);

LinearLayout two = new LinearLayout(this);
two.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
two.addView(gView2, 150, 200);
two.addView(gView3, 150, 150);

layout.addView(two);
```

Try not using that way of giving size to a `View`, you should use `setLayoutParams`.

For instance your layout should have something like:

```
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: Hi chrisbunney,

Actually its good that it will all handled with layout file but I didn't get success. Can you plaese tell how I get achived via layout file. If this work is done by using layoutfile then it means problem is resolved

Comment: I am getting GraphicalView through code and now I want to reference it to layout file. So that I can control others layout parameter which is difficult to handle with code. For example if I want to set layout parameters layout_X and layout_Y then its good that I use layout xml file.

Please suggest! any suggestions will be highly appreciated and if want more clarification then please tell.

Comment: @shobhit: to use the layout file you need to call `setContentView()` from your `Activity's onCreate()` method. I don't know what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply!

I want to set the layout parameters like layout_X and layout_Y for GraphicalView. Can you please tell how can I do?

Comment: @shobhit: From the code? using `.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(x, y));`

Comment: in this way i can control width and height of the view but i want to control x and y coordinates of the view