# Dynamically creating Android controls in C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get to grips with the Monodroid in Visual Studio. Is there a way to use C# to dynamically create multiple controls for an android layout?

I'm used to ASP.NET and so would have thought something like the following would make sense- however with this being XML and not ASP I'm a little stuck.

```
PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();

Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = "some text";
myLabel.ID = "label ID";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
```

etc.

Any suggestions for advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalents for Placeholders are Layouts including:

- LinearLayout -default orientation of horizontal
- RelativeLayout
- GridLayout
- FrameLayout

There are plenty of tutorials for how to use these in XML - eg http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/

And you can also manipulate these in code - using the ViewGroup Methods - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html - e.g, using AddView

You'll find plenty of java examples of this and they port very quickly to monodroid - eg [create layout through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271215/create-layout-through-code)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is most helpful.